# Filename format matcher

Tags: java, jsp

Can you please help me? I have a few files in a folder with formats of

```
SNS20110201.A001
SNS201102.A001
SNS20110201.A003
SNS201102.A003
```

I need to display these files based on file format, e.g.:

```
SNSYYYYMMDD.A001
SNSYYYYMMDD.A003
```

Under one div in UI

```
SNSYYYYMM.A001
SNSYYYYMM.A003
```

Under another div in UI in the same jsp page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the letters before the date format are always the same (or it's the same number of letters), and the file extension is always the same length, then just sort the files by filename length into one array for each length, then iterate through one array per div.

Answer (score 0):

Does this regexp file filter address the heart of the problem?

```
File[] yyyymmddFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.matches("^SNS\\d{8}.A\\d+$");
    }
});

File[] yyyymmFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.matches("^SNS\\d{6}.A\\d+$");
    }
});
```